# Proper mysqli_query and mysqli_error configuration

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When launching my code I get a failed query and the following errors:

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in
>
> mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in

```
<?php
include('mysql_config.php');

function mysqlConnect()
{
    global $mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database;
    $link = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) 
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($link,$mysql_database) or die('Could not select database');
    return $link;
}

function mysqliClose($link)
{
    mysqli_close($link);
}

function sendQuery($query)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error("could not query"));
    return $result;
}
```

?>

How do I properly format the mysqli_query and mysqli_error functions?

Comment: Where did `$link` come from? Check your `sendQuery` function.. Error is clear.. `$link` is not defined..

Comment: You have a scope problem: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You better consider to change `or die(...)` approach to error handling. See http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die for starters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in the code above:

- You missed to declare `$link` `global` as `$mysql_hostname` etc.
- You passed the wrong argument type to `mysqli_error()` it expects `mysqli` and you passed a `string`

I have changed your example:

```
<?php

include('mysql_config.php');

// declaring an additional global var.
$link = NULL;

function mysqlConnect()
{
    global $link; // using the global $link
    global $mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database;
    $link = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) 
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_select_db($link,$mysql_database) or die('Could not select database');
    return $link;
}

function mysqliClose($link)
{
    mysqli_close($link);
}

function sendQuery($query)
{
    global $link; // using the global $link
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Query failed: '
      . mysqli_error($link)); // note $link is the param
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: In a statement `die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error())` you better use `mysqli_connect_error()` instead of `mysqli_error()`. See [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman I agree on that. I just took the code from the OP. Not sure if it's worth to change the answer 8 years later, especially because I'm not coding PHP since years :) ... Feel free to edit it!