# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to build a simple custom CMS, but I'm getting an error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be MySQLi, null given in

Why am I getting this error? All my code is already MySQLi and I am using two parameters, not one.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxxx");

//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

function getPosts() {
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Blog");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<div class=\"blogsnippet\">";
        echo "<h4>" . $row['Title'] . "</h4>" . $row['SubHeading'];
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you accessing the `getPosts` function?

Comment: ..and passing `$con` variable to it?

Comment: This is a scoping issue. You need to pass `$con` to `getPosts()`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this is a scoping issue. Specifically, `$con` is not in scope within your `getPosts` function.

You should pass your connection object in as a dependency, eg

```
function getPosts(mysqli $con) {
    // etc
```

I would also highly recommend halting execution if your connection fails or if errors occur. Something like this should suffice

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); // throw exceptions
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxxx");

getPosts($con);
```

Comment: so this is unneed in mysql? for some reason this only happens with mysqli?

Comment: The (deprecated) MySQL extension would use the last known connection if the `$link_identifier` argument was not passed in to functions like `mysql_query`. The MySQLi extension offers no such convenience.

Answer (score 12):

use global scope on your $con and put it inside your getPosts() function
like so.

```
function getPosts() {
global $con;
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Blog");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<div class=\"blogsnippet\">";
        echo "<h4>" . $row['Title'] . "</h4>" . $row['SubHeading'];
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getPosts()` function seems to be expecting `$con` to be global, but you're not declaring it as such.

A lot of programmers regard bald global variables as a "code smell". The alternative at the other end of the scale is to always pass around the connection resource. Partway between the two is a singleton call that always returns the same resource handle.