# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli null given in - anyone can fix it?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php


$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paginate WHERE IDmen='$name11'");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records

//break total records into pages
$total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page); 

?>
```

I am getting this error:

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home//public_html/load-more-men.php on line 4
>   mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home//public_html/load-more-men.php on line 5
>   Division by zero in /home//public_html/load-more-men.php on line 8

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in)

Comment: You need to create the connection you're referencing with `$connecDb`.  Try adding `$connecDb = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database_name');` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$connecDB = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paginate WHERE IDmen='$name11'");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records

//break total records into pages
$total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page); 

?>
```