# Getting error with mysqli_query()

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

I am getting this type of error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in

What i've been doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
<?php

require('config.php');

function showAll() {
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM cont")or die(mysqli_error());
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);


    $data = array();
    while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $data[] = $row;     
    }
    return $data;   
}

?>
```

Comment: Does your config.php declared $connect

Comment: You have multiple options you can pass `$connection` to the function or "bad idea" use `global $connection` in function, please read about the scopes http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Your $connect is outof scope, inject it into yourfunction

Comment: You've been doing something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is saying that your $connect is null, is your connection is ok?
Have you created connection to the mysql server like this :

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Another thing that may go wrong is here :

```
 while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $data[] = $row;     
    }
```

Your $res variable is an array with 1 result, and the while loop requires mysql resource (the query variable in your case).
You should probobly try this :

```
 while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $data[] = $row;     
    }
```

Comment: He's having problem with variable scope, please add it to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
global $connect;
```

to the start of `function showAll()` and the function where you have `$connect = mysqli_connect()`

Answer (score -3):

There is a problem in `$connect`. Make sure that parameters passed in `$connect` are correct.

```
$connect("localhost","root","password","databaseName");
```