# <b>Warning</b>: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in <b>

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

Here is my code and i am using phpMyAdmin

The json:{"tag":"register","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"JSON Error occured in Registartion"}

Error messaage:Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value < of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

DB_connect.php

```
    <?php
 class DB_Connect {

// constructor
function __construct() {

}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // $this->close();
}

// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    require_once 'include/config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQLi: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
    // selecting database
    //mysqli_select_db($con,DB_DATABASE);

    // return database handler
    return $con;
}

// Closing database connection
public function close() {
    mysqli_close();
}

 }

?>
```

DB_Functions.php

```
 <?php

   class DB_Functions {

private $dbcon;

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->dbcon = new DB_Connect();
    $this->dbcon->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}


/**
 * Random string which is sent by mail to reset password
 */

       public function random_string()
      {
      $character_set_array = array();
$character_set_array[] = array('count' => 7, 'characters' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
$character_set_array[] = array('count' => 1, 'characters' => '0123456789');
$temp_array = array();
foreach ($character_set_array as $character_set) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $character_set['count']; $i++) {
        $temp_array[] = $character_set['characters'][rand(0, strlen($character_set['characters']) - 1)];
    }
}
shuffle($temp_array);
return implode('', $temp_array);
 }


  public function forgotPassword($forgotpassword, $newpassword, $salt){
   $result = mysqli_query("UPDATE `users` SET `encrypted_password` ='$newpassword',`salt` = '$salt' 
                      WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'");

 if ($result) {

return true;

 }
else
 {
return false;
 }

   }
      /**
     * Adding new user to mysql database
     * returns user details
     */

   public function storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $password) {
       $uuid = uniqid('', true);
       $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
      $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
      $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
      $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users(unique_id, firstname, lastname, email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at)    VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname',   '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Verifies user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $salt = $result['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $result;
        }
    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}


      /**
      * Check user is existed or not
     */
     public function isUserExisted($email) {
       $result = mysqli_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
           // user existed 
           return true;
      } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Encrypting password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}

    }

 ?>
```

index.php

```
   <?php

 /**
  PHP API for Login, Register, Changepassword, Resetpassword Requests and    for Email Notifications.
      **/

 if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // Get tag
$tag = $_POST['tag'];

// Include Database handler
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
// response Array
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

// check for tag type
if ($tag == 'login') {
    // Request type is check Login
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check for user
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
    if ($user != false) {
        // user found
        // echo json with success = 1
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["firstname"];
        $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lastname"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $response["user"]["uname"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];

   echo json_encode($response);
             } else {
             // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
              $response["error"] = 1;
              $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
              echo json_encode($response);
          }
      } 
       else if ($tag == 'chgpass'){
       $email = $_POST['email'];

         $newpassword = $_POST['newpas'];


 $hash = $db->hashSSHA($newpassword);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"];
  $subject = "Change Password Notification";
     $message = "Hello User,\n\nYour Password is sucessfully changed.\n\nRegards,\ntest Team.";
      $from = "test@test.com";
      $headers = "From:" . $from;
 if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {

           $user = $db->forgotPassword($email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
       if ($user) {
           $response["success"] = 1;
           mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
           echo json_encode($response);
         }
            else {
            $response["error"] = 1;
            echo json_encode($response);
            }


        // user is already existed - error response


    } 
       else {

        $response["error"] = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User not exist";
         echo json_encode($response);

    }
    }
       else if ($tag == 'forpass'){
       $forgotpassword = $_POST['forgotpassword'];

         $randomcode = $db->random_string();


       $hash = $db->hashSSHA($randomcode);
         $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
         $salt = $hash["salt"];
         $subject = "Password Recovery";
        $message = "Hello User,\n\nYour Password is sucessfully changed. Your new Password is $randomcode . Login with your new Password and change it in the User Panel.\n\nRegards,\ntest Team.";
         $from = "test@test.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
   if ($db->isUserExisted($forgotpassword)) {

$user = $db->forgotPassword($forgotpassword, $encrypted_password, $salt);
      if ($user) {
       $response["success"] = 1;
        mail($forgotpassword,$subject,$message,$headers);
       echo json_encode($response);
     }
    else {
    $response["error"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
     }


        // user is already existed - error response


    } 
       else {

        $response["error"] = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User not exist";
         echo json_encode($response);

  }

 }
    else if ($tag == 'register') {
      // Request type is Register new user
      $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $lname = $_POST['lname'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $uname = $_POST['uname'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      $subject = "Registration";
       $message = "Hello $fname,\n\nYou have sucessfully registered to our service.\n\nRegards,\nAdmin.";
        $from = "test@test.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;

      // check if user is already existed
                // store user
       // $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $password);
        $user = $db->storeUser($first_name, $last_name, $email, $zica_number, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["firstname"];
        $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lastname"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $response["user"]["uname"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];

            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "JSON Error occured in Registartion";
            echo json_encode($response);

    }
} else {
     $response["error"] = 3;
     $response["error_msg"] = "JSON ERROR";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
  echo "Login API";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in)

Answer (score 0):

Few of your mysqli_query missing `$con` - Connection variable

```
$result = mysqli_query("UPDATE `users` SET `encrypted_password` ='$newpassword',`salt` = '$salt' 
                      WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'");

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
```

add `$con`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `users` SET `encrypted_password` ='$newpassword',`salt` = '$salt' 
                      WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
```

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in <b>/home/u920260681/public_html/login_api/include/DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>67</b><br />

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.login_app.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute
at com.login_app.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
at android.os.Looper.loop
at android.app.ActivityThread.main

Comment: echo $con variable. I think some problem in connection variable

Answer (score 0):

you have misses `$con` in some places.

Check this

In `getUserByEmailAndPassword()`

```
$result = mysqli_query("","SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
                       ^// connection object is misssing as first parameter
```

Even here(in `forgotPassword()`)

```
$result = mysqli_query("","UPDATE `users` SET `encrypted_password` ='$newpassword',`salt` = '$salt' WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'");
                       ^// here
```

Again here(in `isUserExisted()`)

```
$result = mysqli_query("","SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
                        ^
```