# PHP mysqli_query error in syntax

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with my code. I think it's good but the console says its not:

> Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **/home/u772833821/public_html/DB_Functions.php** on line **66**

Here is the code :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users SET (email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
```

Comment: What is the code at line 66?

Comment: Please share the code of DB_Function.php

Comment: place below code after `mysqli_connect` line. `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno());
}
` and check error message

Comment: Remove `SET` from `INSERT`

Comment: Where is `$con` set?

Comment: I added the "if" lane and removed SET from INSERT and nothing changed.

Comment: RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in)

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Plus, that error is not from your query, but from your connection.

Comment: The `set` made it an invalid query, separate issue from connection failing (your query also could still be invalid depending on what variables contain, look into prepared statements). Is this code in a function, did you include your db connection file, a lot of guessing still here...

Comment: @chris85 heh, yep. I'm thinking this question's leaning towards mixing MySQL APIs, or their connection codes are off.

Comment: I would sugess you to bind your parameters to prevent sql injection and to make sur that your query works, because it will handle simple and double quote  See this link for more information :  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: can you keep the guesswork out of things and edit your question to contain what you're using to connect with?? You're one vote away from your question being closed but that may change soon and will take more time to reopen it, if/when it does.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is incorrect. Try as below :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users (email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
```

Try to check `$con` is valid or not:

```
$host = "your_host"; // replace these settings for your own
$username = "your_username";
$password = "your_password_if_any";
$db = "your_db_name";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

if (!$con) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: Nothing changed. The same warning

Comment: Will you add your db connection in your question?

Comment: @TheLietuvis Never show any db info here not even host (unless localhost for demonstration) or username

Comment: @TheLietuvis : Please check connection mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps, there are more then one correction:

**1.** Remove SET from INSERT query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users (email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
```

**2.** Check connection error

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if (!$con) {
  echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
  echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
  echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
  exit;
}
```

Perhaps issue with connection. Let me know what is the output from point **2**.