# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ../ on line 7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having some problems with my website. The domain is **bitcointap.xyz**.
On the /register & /login page. I'm having some PHP errors. On the /register page (bitcointap.xyz/register) I get the error:

`"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ../ on line 7"`

Register.php: http://pastebin.com/4pqvyiL1

Another problem I'm having is with the Login.php page. I get the error;

```
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ../ on line 9
```

Login.php: http://pastebin.com/ednfCE1y

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Whats the content of `db.php and dbc.php`?

Comment: @Robert Refer this link to check the connection is correct or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877694/php-mysqli-query-error-in-syntax/34877731#34877731

Comment: Make sure `settings` is a valid table.

Comment: db: http://pastebin.com/Yf3WzaKc
dbc: http://pastebin.com/VWepjuYg

Comment: i don't think I have any tables, not really sure how to create them @Matt

Comment: @Robert If you don't have any table then how the query will work?

Comment: Make sure your table exist

Comment: @AnkiiG I'm using an old script of mine, I'm also kind of new to all this so I'm not sure how to create tables.

Comment: Go to your phpMyAdmin (localhost/phpmyadmin) and , follow to your database , then see your settings table

Comment: There are no tables in the database

Comment: As Ankiig is saying we need to see db.php i suspect you your connection fails try to handle connection erros as described in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @JoaquinJavi The connection is valid, it looks like it's a problem with the database tables. (Their are none)

Comment: So there is the error you're trying to fetch 0 rows so its returns false

Comment: @Robert do you have table structure? Are you able to create that?

Comment: @AnkiiG no i don't think there is a table structure. is it possible to upload my .zip here? i might have it but i'm not sure

Comment: @Robert Zip file of database?

Comment: Please add some code as shown in my answer for properly intercepting connection errors. Displaying **$con->connect_errno** and **$con->connect_error** would give us more information about the reason the connection is failing.

Answer (score -1):

My guess: the connection failed. The result then will be **false** (boolean).
In consequence, **mysql_query($con, …)** tries to use a connection handle which is **false**.
The manual says:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($con===false) {
    echo 'Connection failed (' . $con->connect_errno . '): ' . $con->connect_error;
    exit(1);
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `settings`");
if ($result===false) {
    echo 'Selection failed :' . $con->error;
    exit(2);
}
$settings = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
// ...
```

So, you should look at your includes **include 'db.php'** and **include 'dbc.php'**, which define the connection parameters.