# How to fix: Warning: mysqli_get_server_info() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm very bad in PHP and I'm trying to install arfoo.com on my host. I had some problem with mysql and mysqli, which are fixed now.

But now I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_get_server_info() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/***/install/step4.php on line 47

For the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Arfooo
 * 
 * @package    Arfooo
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) Arfooo Annuaire (fr) and Arfooo Directory (en)
 *             by Guillaume Hocine (c) 2007 - 2010
 *             http://www.arfooo.com/ (fr) and http://www.arfooo.net/ (en)
 * @author     Guillaume Hocine & Adrian Galewski
 * @license    http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/fr/ Creative Commons
 */
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('languages/' . $_SESSION['selectedLanguage'] . '.php'); 

$chemin_includes_header = 'includes/';
include_once($chemin_includes_header.'header.php'); 

require_once("dbfunctions.php"); 
require_once("createdb.php");

function createDbConfig($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName, $dbPrefix)
{
    $dbConfig['DB_HOST'] = $dbHost;
    $dbConfig['DB_USER'] = $dbUser;
    $dbConfig['DB_PASS'] = $dbPass;
    $dbConfig['DB_NAME'] = $dbName;
    $dbConfig['DB_PREFIX'] = $dbPrefix;
    $dbConfig['DB_INSTALLED'] = true;

    $data = "<?php\n \$dbConfig = " . var_export($dbConfig, true). ";\n ?>";
    file_put_contents("../config/db.php", $data);
}

$_SESSION['mysqlServer'] = $_POST['mysqlServer'];
$_SESSION['mysqlUser'] = $_POST['mysqlUser'];
$_SESSION['mysqlPassword'] = $_POST['mysqlPassword'];
$_SESSION['mysqlDatabaseName'] = $_POST['mysqlDatabaseName'];
$_SESSION['mysqlTablesPrefix'] = $_POST['mysqlTablesPrefix'];

dbConnect($_SESSION['mysqlServer'],
          $_SESSION['mysqlUser'],
          $_SESSION['mysqlPassword'],
          $_SESSION['mysqlDatabaseName']
          );

$mysqlVersion = mysqli_get_server_info();    

$mysqlVersionCorrect = version_compare($mysqlVersion, "4.1", ">=");

if($mysqlVersionCorrect)
{

    createDbConfig($_POST['mysqlServer'],
                   $_POST['mysqlUser'],
                   $_POST['mysqlPassword'],
                   $_POST['mysqlDatabaseName'],
                   $_POST['mysqlTablesPrefix']);



    $tablesList = createDbTables($_POST['mysqlTablesPrefix'],
                                 $_SESSION['siteRootUrl'],
                                 $_SESSION['selectedLanguage'],
                                 $_SESSION['urlRewriting']
                                 );
}
else
{
    $tablesList = array();
}

?>
```

EDIT:

```
function dbConnect($server, $user, $pass, $dbName)
{

    /* install database with prefixed tables */

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbName);
    //mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die('could not connect to mysql');;

    mysqli_query($conn, 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table');
    //mysqli_query($dbName, 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table`');
    //mysql_query('create database IF NOT EXISTS ' . $dbName);

    mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbName) or die('could not select database');
}
```

Any kind help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in)

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the object returned by `mysqli_connect()` as argument to `mysqli_get_server_info()` if you want to use the *procedural style*.

```
$mysqlConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");
$mysqlVersion = mysqli_get_server_info($mysqlConnect);
```

Or using the *OO style* :

```
$mysqlConnect = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");
$mysqlVersion = $mysqlConnect->server_info;
```

See more at http://php.net/mysqli_get_server_info

**EDIT :**

Your dbConnect() function should return the mysqli object, try to add `return $conn;` at the end, like that :

```
function dbConnect($server, $user, $pass, $dbName)
{

    /* install database with prefixed tables */

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbName);
    //mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die('could not connect to mysql');;

    mysqli_query($conn, 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table');
    //mysqli_query($dbName, 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table`');
    //mysql_query('create database IF NOT EXISTS ' . $dbName);

    mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbName) or die('could not select database');

    return $conn;
}
```

Comment: as dummie, I tried to do this: $mysqlConnect = dbConnect($_SESSION['mysqlServer'],
          $_SESSION['mysqlUser'],
          $_SESSION['mysqlPassword'],
          $_SESSION['mysqlDatabaseName']
          );

$mysqlVersion = mysqli_get_server_info($mysqlConnect); but it didn't work

Comment: Can you show me your `dbConnect()` function (edit your question to add it) ?

Comment: I'd highly appreciate if you give me a code to copy and paste. I really no nothing about PHP :(

Comment: I need to know what `dbConnect()` returns, try to find it in the included files (like **dbfunctions.php** or **createdb.php**)

Comment: Add `return $conn;` at the end of the `dbConnect()` function, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this:
Warning: mysqli_get_server_info() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /install/step4.php on line 47

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109516/discussion-between-aurel-and-kardo).