# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in Operations.php on line 19

Tags: php, mysqli

I have Connection class and Operations class
when call the required method which is used to insert the record to the database , that shows the error.

**File Name : Connection.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Connection class to make "connection" with database
*/
class Connection  
{   
    public $host;
    public $user;
    public $password;
    public $databaseName;

    /**
    * Constructor
    */
public  function __construct()
    {   
        $this->host = '';
        $this->user = '';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->databaseName = '';

        $this->connect();
    }
    /**
    * The method that make the connection to the database
    */
```

Connection method which is used to establish the connection

```
    public function connect()
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->databaseName);
        if(!$con){
            echo "Connect to the database failed";
        }

        return $con;
    }

}
```

**FIle Name : Operations.php**

```
 require_once"Connection.php";

    class Operations
    {
        //$Connection = new Connection();
        //$con = $Connection->connect();
        function __construct()
        {
            $Connection = new Connection();
            $con = $Connection->connect();
        }
```

When i call this following function, it's show me the error

```
        public function add_main_menu($title, $title_ara, $image)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO menu (title, title_ara, image) VALUES ('$title', '$title_ara', '$image')";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            return $result;
        }

        public function add_sub_menu($title, $title_ara, $price, $description, $descreption_ara, $image, $menu_id){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO sub_menu (title, title_ara, price, description, description_ara, image, menu_id) VALUES ('$title', '$title_ara', $price, '$description', '$description_ara', '$image', '$menu_id')";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your last function, you spelled the parameter incorrectly: `$descreption_ara` instead of `$description_ara`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862743/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given-in)

Comment: also, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php

Comment: Okay, but I didn't call the last function yet

Comment: As @Federkun has mentioned, your issue is likely related to scope, not the typo.

Comment: Variable `$con` in `__construct` is __not available__ elsewhere

Comment: Try to declare $con as private: `private $con;`, then assign $con to the Connection.

Comment: so, what is the solution ?

Comment: The solution is to learn PHP/OOP properly.

Comment: The error is caused by the "connect" method , I used mysqli_connect this was the issue

Comment: Are you sure `host`, `username`, `password`, `databaseName` variables are assigned?

Comment: I found the problem , the solution is replace "mysqli_connect" with "new mysqli" in the method "connect" , thank you all :)

Comment: You will get another problem even after you solved this problem. Change `mysqli_query($con, $sql);` to `mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);`.

Comment: You are right , thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Connection.php** as following,

```
<?php
class Connection  
{   
    public $host;
    public $user;
    public $password;
    public $databaseName;

public  function __construct($host,$user,$password,$database)
    {   
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->databaseName = $database;

        $this->connect();
    }
```

Now change the  **Operations.php file** as following

```
 require_once"Connection.php";
    class Operations
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $Connection = new Connection("host","user","passwrd","database");
            $con = $Connection->connect();
        }
```

Comment: Still giving me same error , Thanks for your effort